# PyGTK setting text of an entry (absolute beginner)

Tags: pygtk

I'm a total PyGTK noob, just to get that out there.
I'm trying to set an entry's text with this code:

```
def on_button1_clicked(self, builder, data = None):
    gtk.Entry(txtInput).set_text("Hello")
```

but when I click the button I get a type error asking for an integer somewhere on the second line of that code. What's going on? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and Google hasn't helped.
TIA

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What is `txtInput`?

Answer (score 1):

The `txtInput` should be an integer.
It's the maximum length of the entry (or 0 for maximum).
See [gtk.Entry Class Reference](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkentry.html).